# How to pass argument for function in controller from view

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have function in controller with one argument and now I want to pass value for it from view through url.

### courses.php

```
public function index($id){
   print_r();
   exit;
}
```

### coursesview.php

```
<a class="jscroll-next" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/courses/index?page=<?php echo $nextPage; ?>&id=<?php echo $parentId ?>">next page</a>
```

How it possible?

Comment: `$this->uri->segment('3');` can help you to get the value from url

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods

Check the above link

Comment: Consider checking my answer and update me if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view),
Simply put the parameter in an array and pass it to the view by using the second parameter of `load->view()`.

Afterwards, in the view, the variable will be available as the key.
In this example: `$id` or `$anothervar`.

**courses.php**

```
public function index($id){
  $data = array('id' => $id, 'anothervar' => 'yeahi');
  $this->load->view('coursesview', $data);
  // exit;
}
```

**coursesview.php**

```
echo $id; // the ID
echo $anothervar; // "yeahi"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to use minimum arguments in URL, here is my suggestions

```
1.<a class="jscroll-next" href="<?php echo base_url('courses/$nextPage/$parentId/'); ?>">next page</a> //controller followed by arguments -  if you call index method

(OR)

2.<a class="jscroll-next" href="<?php echo base_url('courses/methodname/$nextPage/$parentId/'); ?>">next page</a> //controller,method name and followed by arguments
```

How to get those arguments in controller
Example:

```
$nextPage =  $this->uri->segment(3);
$parentId =  $this->uri->segment(4);
```